# set element values using foreach not working as expected

Tags: php

I have a muti-dimention array like this:

```
$arrayTest = array(0=>array("label"=>"test","category"=>"test","content"=>array(0=>array("label"=>"test","category"=>"test"),1=>array("label"=>"test","category"=>"test"))));
```

then I want to set all the labels in the content array like this:

```
foreach($arrayTest as $obj) {
    foreach($obj["content"] as $anobj){
        $anobj["label"] = "hello";
    }
}
```

After that I print out the array

```
echo json_encode($arrayTest);
```

On the browser I saw:

```
[{"label":"test","category":"test","content":[{"label":"test","category":"test"},{"label":"test","category":"test"}]}]
```

Nothing changed, but if I try

```
$arrayTest[0]["content"][0]["label"] = "hello";
$arrayTest[0]["content"][1]["label"] = "hello";
```

Then it seems working. I want to know why the first method not working?

Comment: from the manual: ["In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array by reference for the changes to stick:

```
foreach($arrayTest as &$obj) { // by reference
    foreach($obj["content"] as &$anobj){ // by reference
        $anobj["label"] = "hello";
    }
}

// Whenever you iterate by reference it's a good idea to unset the variables
// when finished, because assigning to them again will have unexpected results.
unset($obj);
unset($anobj);
```

Alternatively, you can index into the array using keys, starting from the root:

```
foreach($arrayTest as $key1 => $obj) {
    foreach($obj["content"] as $key2 => $anobj){
        $arrayTest[$key1]["content"][$key2]["label"] = "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool it works, thank you! I will accept your answer after 10mins :) since the system constraints